# Get the list of hostnames connected in LAN for Windows Store Apps

Tags: network-programming, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I actually tried with the following code, which gave me a result of the local machine Ip address, name and the server Ip address

```
var hostNamesList = NetworkInformation.GetHostNames();
                    HostName serverHost = new HostName("cptdomain.ctl.local");
                    StreamSocket clientSocket = new Windows.Networking.Sockets.StreamSocket();

                    // Try to connect to the remote host
                    await clientSocket.ConnectAsync(serverHost, "http");


                    foreach (var entry in hostNamesList)
                    {
                        if (entry.Type == HostNameType.DomainName)
                        {
                 hostName.Text = "Machine Name : " + entry.DisplayName;
                 IPAddress.Text = "Machine IP : " + clientSocket.Information.LocalAddress.DisplayName;
                 ServerAddress.Text = "Server IP : " + clientSocket.Information.RemoteAddress.DisplayName;

                            }
                    }
                }
```

But actually my requirement is, how to get the list of IP addresses and name of the computers that are connected to the server in LAN for Windows Store Apps.

Please guide me in this to get the proper solution for running my store app.

**Note:** Here I was working with windows8 store apps with WinRT

Answer (score 0):

This is how you do it in a [full fat c# application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16113/Retreiving-a-list-of-network-computer-names-using), but I don't think you can do this on a winrt application. At a minimum you will have to add the private network privilege.

Comment: Please suggest me on how to do in WinRT Application.

Comment: It can't be done. You don't have access to the api's required.